# Angular custom tag not rendering and executing function

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-components, custom-tag

I have a custom tag in html. In my  next.component.ts file I have,

```
@Component({
  selector: 'nextbutton',
  template: ` <button (click) = "nextfunc()">Next</button> `
})

export class NextComponent{

  nextfunc() {
```

==>>my app.component.html file

```
<div>
<!--other tags-->
<next-button></next-button>

</div>
```

I am not able to render the button and access the nextfunc()

===>>My app.module.ts

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NextComponent } from './next.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NextComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

===>>my next.component.ts

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'nextbutton',
  template: ` <button (click) = "nextfunc()">Next</button> `
})

export class NextComponent{

  nextfunc() {
     //do something
  }
}
```

Comment: change the selector to `nextbutton to next-button`

Comment: it worked. thanks. Maybe the localhost rendering was slow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Selector in Directive/Component is **nextbutton** while you are using tag as

```
 <next-button></next-button>
```

Either change your Selector to **next-button** or change tag to **nextbutton**

Comment: it worked. thanks. Maybe the localhost rendering was slow